# LVM - after server reboot data changes of last 6 month lost

Tags: linux, lvm, data-loss

I have a server setup with a Proxmox VE on LVM groups. Today I could not kill some processes, so I decided to reboot the server. This did not work eighter so I had to press the reset button. After the server booted up, the data on the server was set 6 month back in time. All files that were created since then are gone now.

1) What has happend?

2) Is there any way to get back my data?

Comment: `Is there any way to get back my data` - Restore from your backups?

Comment: It sounds like you had a snapshot taken and have mounted that instead of the regular filesystem, or you were using a snapshot before and not the regular filesystem for changes.

Comment: @mtinberg: Thanks for your reply. How can I validate this?

Comment: You can check /var/log/messages /var/log/kern.log /var/log/syslog (depending on your distro and configuration) to check if there was a snapshot created.